# Facebook share - posts not appear at recent posts

Tags: php, facebook

I've got some messy thing with Facebook "Share this" module. 
Some time ago Share button stopped working properly. When someone clicks Share this, link with content appear at his wall, but people can't see this action in recent posts, they need to open his/her wall to see this. What happened with Facebook? Anyone know?

Comment: This might be because facebook cache which takes time to post it. If you duplicating the message it wont let you post more than one. so please make sure you post different message and if possible to different account..

Comment: it's for sure different message, and I was trying different accounts with my friends..

Answer (score 0):

It is probably determined to be low quality by Facebook algorithms and thus not showing in the recent feed.  If this is published via an application, check the insights on your application.